# render task list in react, problem with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, arraylist

I have a problem wanting to conditionally render a task group depending on whether they are marked as performed or pending.

```
function TaskList() {
  const { tasks } = useContext(TaskContext);

  return tasks.length === 0 ? (
    <h2>No hay tareas agregadas</h2>
  ) : (
    <section className="task-list">
      <div className="pending-task">
        <h3>Tareas pendientes:</h3>
        <ul className="list">
          {tasks.filter((t) => t.done === false).length === 0 ? (
            <h4>No hay tareas por realizar</h4> // In case there is no task to do, you should render this
          ) : (
            tasks
              .filter((t) => t.done === false)
              .map((t, i) => <TaskCard key={t.id} task={t} index={i} />) //here are rendered those that are pending
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="done-task">
        <h3>Tareas realizadas:</h3>
        <ul className="list">
          {tasks.filter((t) => t.done === true).length === 0 ? (
            <h4>No ha realizado ninguna tarea</h4> //In case no task has been performed I still want to show this
          ) : (
            tasks
              .filter((t) => t.done === true)
              .map((t, i) => <TaskCard key={t.id} task={t} index={i} />) //here are rendered the ones I already made
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

But when I put it to the test and click the button to mark the task as done, I throw the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'done') at TaskList.jsx:16:34
```

What would be this line here:

```
tasks.filter((t) => t.done === false).length === 0
```

I am aware that this error can occur because when filtering an array without elements, you cannot find the specified *done* property.

the funny thing is that after the app has been bugled due to the aforementioned error, if I refresh the page, the app works again and the task in which I clicked appears marked, that is, the bug is deleted, so I don’t know what I’m doing wrong, I have a couple of months practicing with react and there are things I’m learning.

Comment: You're getting that error because at the moment you're using the 'done' property it's coming back as undefined. To aid in further debugging you can simply add a check for tasks before your return like so: `if(!tasks){ return <h2>Loading Tasks...</h2>;}` This should help give your project time to read whether or not the task's 'done' property is set before trying to read that property.

Comment: I understand but it doesn’t work that way

Answer (score 1):

This is part of my context:

```
const [tasks, setTask] = useState([]);

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => setTask(data), []); 

// Here the value of *data* comes from an import that is an array that reads the tasks stored in the browser localstorage
```

Comment: Here I see that you have a hook set up to store the task but that will only fire once since your dependency array of the useEffect is empty. If you're reading data from localStorage setTask won't set after you edited the data in localeStorage. It'll only fire once on first load and never again if you manipulate the data after the first load. hence why you're probably still seeing the undefined error

Comment: So should you place *data* or *task*? as a dependency or both? so that it is updated when the values change, forgive that part I did not understand very well, there are some concepts that I am learning.

Comment: Without seeing the code in it's entirety I'm not too certain but from what I gather you'll want to start with adding just _task_ to the dependency array. All the dependency array does is keep an eye on the state that you put in it, so when the state changes it runs the function in your useEffect. Here is a link to understand it better [useEffect Reference](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#reference).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that that the tasks array in the TaskContext is properly initialized and contains valid task objects with the done property and tasks array is not null or undefined when the TaskList component is rendered. You can add a null check before rendering the component to handle such cases.

```js
if (!tasks) {
  return null // or render a loading state
}
```

Comment: The check is within that same component in this line:  *return tasks.length === 0 ? (
    <h2>No hay tareas agregadas</h2>
  ) : (
    <section className="task-list"></section> *

Comment: my problem is not with the empty array, my problem is with the conditional rendering of tasks marked as pending and those marked as done. The problem is that by filtering the array to separate the to-dos from the tasks done, if there are no tasks to be filtered logically you will be looking for a property that does not exist within an empty array

Comment: i am not sure how you have defined and setting context. But sometime you have to give time for the cotext to set depending on your code. I made the assumption that the initial value of your tasks context is undefined then eventually it gets set.  tasks.length === 0 will throw error if the the task itself is undefined during the first render.

Comment: I don’t think I understood correctly, my problem is filtering the tasks that are already created, separating them.

Comment: why don't you add const { tasks } = useContext(TaskContext);  this lines TaskContext file with your question. It will be helpful to  debug i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this line

```
tasks.filter((t) => t.done === false).length === 0
```

with

```
tasks.some((t) => !t?.done)
```